# Removing characters in textbox [vb.net]

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I use a button to locate a file, and it puts the location in the textbox as "C:\file.exe\"
I need the "" so when a user select a folder with a space in it it won't see it as a new input.

```
       OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Dim filename As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    TextBox1.Text = Chr(34) & filename & Chr(34)
```

But later I need the same location of the textbox but without the "" (Chr(34))charachters.
How can I make it so it removes those characters out of the textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove any set of characters from a string using the .Replace method.

```
Dim text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(Chr(34).ToString(),String.Empty)
TextBox1.Text = text
```

Comment: When i run it i get this error "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'TextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

Comment: Very strange, when i build it, it works, but in debug it gives an error.